# SDL_TTF Manual Line Ending

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2, ttf

With SDL TTF I've already gotten automatic line wrapping down using the built in "wrapped" function.

However, now I want to do what I guess you could call manual line wrapping. Basically, at certain points I want to start a new line.

Specifically, every time there is a open square bracket "[" I want to do a line ending, and continue the text on a new line. (The equivalent of hitting enter)

Any help would be awesome! (/n doesn't work with SDL TTF as far as I know)

Answer (score 1):

The `\n` [is supposed to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18418688/301166) in the _Wrapped() function calls.
So just replace the `[` character with a `\n` character.

Answer (score -1):

That did the trick! Thanks!

To restate for future users:
Using the "_Wrapped()" function, '/n' does actually work as you'd expect. But not in the other TTF modes.